# Understanding the point of a kölsche Witz

Tags: joke

> Zwei kölsche Putzfrauen bei der Arbeit. Die eine: „Ich mach’ Diät.“ Darauf die andere: „Jot, dann maach ich die Finster.“

I can guess that 'Diät' here is a play on words for something like 'die …' but fail to see what it is.

Comment: Note that even native German speakers will fail to see the point if they are not familiar with Kölsch.

Answer (score 41):

You are right. It's a play on words for Diät. But it only works out for the Cologne dialect (or similar ones).

> Ich mach' Diät

means

> I'm dieting.

But these two women are from Cologne and in their dialect it can be understood as

> Ich mach die [Ääd](https://www.koelsch-woerterbuch.de/erde-auf-koelsch-4.html) (Ääd = Erde)

which can be translated as

> I will take care of (clean) the ground.

Sooo ... the one cleaner says "I'm dieting", but the other one understands "I will clean the floor". Therefore she responds she will clean the windows.

---

Einen Witz zu erklären ist wie einen Frosch zu sezieren.
Du bist danach schlauer aber der Frosch ist tot. ^^

Comment: Einen Frosch seziert man hoffentlich erst, wenn er sowieso schon tot ist ^^

Comment: Stichwort: Vivisektion ...

Comment: Elaboration for non-German speakers: "die Erde" (the earth) is often informally used to mean "the floor". Even when it is a non ground level floor in a building.

Comment: Oh, and: "machen" (make) is also very often used to mean "handle, take care of, deal with"

Comment: @rackandboneman Must be a local thing then, because in Austria "der Boden" (the floor) is *way* more common then "die Erde", the latter being almost exclusively being used to refer to the physical ground or the celestial body.

Comment: @MechMK1:  It ain't just a local thing.  I live in Germany a good ways away from Cologne, but my mother in law drives me up the wall by saying "die Erde" instead of "der Boden."

Comment: In some localities, saying "Boden" might make some people think of the attic rather than the floor :)

Comment: @rackandboneman   Yes, but not surprisingly so because the important part of that attic is indeed its floor. Without which all the stuff stored there would crash down.

Comment: @rackandboneman *Boden* for *Dachboden* is like the Americans' *chef* for *chef de cuisine*; it leaves out an important qualification ;-). From an advertising for a language school, phone call to a company: "Hello, I'd like to speak to your chef." "To our chef??" "Yes, I have a date with him." "Oh, well then..."

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Reminds me of *"I only understand train station"*

Comment: "We're sorry, the chef is very loaded at the moment..."